# MiKTeX \usepackage{amsmath} issue

Tags: packages, miktex

Brand new to LaTeX and the MiKTeX installation, so I'm hoping my question has an easy answer. As part of my learning process, I'm trying to use the `amsmath` package and it does not compile as it does when I'm not using a package. Here's my little trial code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  f(x) = x^2
\end{equation*}
```

The console output seems to show styles loading, then states `No file TestScript.aux.` and hangs there. I tried eliminating the `--clean` from the preferences so that an `.aux` file was generated, but I still get a hang.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to be missing `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

The symptoms you describe are quite clear. The console would print

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./TestScript.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
No file TestScript.aux.
)
*
```

and the trailing `*` means that TeX is waiting for input.

A document must have a valid `\end{document}` tag or the LaTeX job will not end.

Depending on the front-end you use, the console output (and the log file) could be different: some of the common front-ends use `-interaction=nonstopmode` which aborts the job in such cases:

```
! Emergency stop.
<*> TestScript.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on TestScript.log.
```